# Express session is not seened in server code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I have server code and index.js code conected to index.html file. everything seemed to be working, but I can't get the next task done.

Task is: If a new user created, and he's redirected to `casino.html` and after this when he will wisit home page, hape page should check if he has session cookie set, and if yes, he should be automaticaly redirected to `casino.html`. But it dont seem to work.

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const uuid = require('uuid').v4
const mysql = require('mysql2')

const app = express()
const PagePassword = '1234'

const pool = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  port:'3306',
  user: 'root',
  password:'1234567890',
  database:'mydb'
})

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('client'))

const sessions ={}



app.post('/', (req,res) =>{
  
    const sesionCheck = req.headers.cookie?.split('=')[1]
    const usersession = sessions[sesionCheck]
    if(usersession){
      document.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/casino.html'
    }else{
      console.log(req.headers)
      const loginCode = `select * from users where nickname="${req.body.nickname}"`
      const PostPasswd = req.body.PostPasswd
    
      pool.query(loginCode, (err,resoult) =>{
    
        if(!resoult.length && PostPasswd==PagePassword){
          //console.log('New user created')
          const code = `INSERT into Users (nickname,points,is_croupier)\nVALUES("${req.body.nickname}",1000, 0);`
          pool.query(code)
    
          //set cookie and session for new user
          
          pool.query(loginCode,  (err,resoult)=>{
    
            const userID =  resoult[resoult.length-1].user_id
            const _nickname = resoult[resoult.length-1].nickname
            const sessionId = uuid()
            sessions[sessionId] = {_nickname, userID}
            res.set('Set-Cookie', `session=${sessionId}`)
            res.json({message: "UserIsCreated"})
            
            console.log('added cookie to' + sessionId)
            console.log(sessions)
        })
    
        }
        
        if(resoult.length){
          if(resoult[resoult.length-1].nickname == req.body.nickname && PostPasswd==PagePassword){
            //ocupated nickname
            res.json({message: "nicknameIsOccupated"})
          }
        }
    
        if(PostPasswd!=PagePassword){
          //invalid password
          console.log('Invalid password')
        }
      }) 
    }
        

  
})


app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log('server is running at port 3000')
})
```

index.js script:

```
const NicknameText = document.getElementById('nickname');
const PasswdText = document.getElementById('passwd');
const LoginButton = document.getElementById('loginBtn');

const ServerURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

LoginButton.onclick = async function Login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(ServerURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            nickname: NicknameText.value,
            PostPasswd: PasswdText.value
        }),
        credentials: 'include'
        
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    if (response.ok) {
        if (data.message === "nicknameIsOccupated") {
            console.log('This nickname is in use!');
            NicknameText.value = ''
            PasswdText.value = ''
            NicknameText.placeholder = "This nickname is in use!"
            const icon = document.createElement('i')
            icon.className = 'fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation'// Assuming you're using Font Awesome
            const container = document.createElement('div')
            container.appendChild(icon)
            NicknameText.appendChild(container)
            // Append the icon and error message to the login button
        } 
        if(data.message === "UserIsCreated"){
            document.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/casino.html';
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Error:', data.message);
    }
};
```

What is the problem?

I just need help with code